# Connection to Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-virtual-network

While trying to connect to my server on Azure using SSMS I get the following error:

> Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access). To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database). (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 47073)

Is there another way to fix this problem other than creating a private endpoint in a virtual network?

I tried selecting a database that the SSMS should actually work with like someone suggested I do, but I still get an error on that side too (this is in SSMS)... Also tried creating a private virtual endpoint, I don't know where I mess it up. I still get the error.

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? If outside Azure, allow public access and whitelist the IPs that needs access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to replicate the issue, I got the same error:

[image]

If you want to connect Azure SQL Database to SSMS which is on-premises, you can directly enable public access of Azure SQL database and whitelist the IP address of SSMS without using private endpoint. You can follow below procedure to do this:

Go Networking of SQL server Enable Selected Network, to whitelist the IP you need to create new Firewall Rule as mentioned below:

[image]

Go to SSMS and try to connect SQL database then you will get a popup to whitelist the IP address as mentioned below:

[image]

If you click on OK, then it will be whitelisted automatically, and SQL database will connect successfully.

[image]

Otherwise, if you want to connect with private endpoint you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905322/how-do-i-connect-to-azure-sql-database-using-private-endpoint-trough-vpn-gateway?rq=2).

Comment: yes, whitelisting the IP is obviously necessary for ssms.